# Is there a standard for this paper size (545 × 398 mm²)?

Tags: paper-size

I got loads of 545 × 398 mm² kraft paper sheets from China.

Does this correspond to a standard ? I can't figure which (and the supplier is of no help), I couldn't match it to any of the ones listed in the [paper size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size) and [ISO 216](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_216) Wikipedia articles or in [this other list](http://resources.printhandbook.com/pages/paper-size-chart.php).

Comment: I believe it should say aaa x bbb mm not mm^2. Please post the answer, when you find it.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't correspond to any standard US sizes (approx. 21x15").

....but you could cut it to fit standard sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have updated the question with some lists I checked before asking. Actually I use it mainly as packing paper, so I'm only asking out of curiosity.